# Can the IDs of the Story Point and Sprint custom fields vary for different projects and workspace for Jira

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api, jira-plugin, jira-agile

Hello StackOverflow community,

I am having difficulty understanding certain aspects of custom fields in Atlassian and would appreciate your guidance. I have the following questions:

Can the "Story Point" and "Estimated Story Point" fields have different IDs across different projects, or are their IDs fixed across all projects?
What does it mean for a custom field to be locked? Is this related to the fixed ID of the custom field?
Is there a way to access a list of custom fields with fixed IDs, if any exist?

In the projects that I have created, the Story Point is fixed as customfield_10033, but from what I have read in forums, I see different IDs.

Thank you for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Fields have same id across projects.

You can fetch all field via API:
https://developer.atlassian.com/cloud/jira/platform/rest/v3/api-group-issue-fields/#api-rest-api-3-field-get

Field ids can differ between Jira instances.

Comment: Thank you for your help. I found a similar [comment](https://community.developer.atlassian.com/t/confirm-variancy-of-jira-cloud-issue-field-keys-for-custom-fields/21134/2) from Atlassian's staff. So, we can say that the IDs of customfields may vary in different projects.

Comment: @melihkizmaz ids can vary between Jira instances but not Jira projects